# long hadoop run, stuck at reduce>reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have hadoop run that basically just aggregate over keys, it's code:
(mapper is the identity mapper)

```
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> results, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            String res = new String("");
            while(values.hasNext())
            {
                res += values.next().toString();
            }
            Text outputValue = new Text("<all><id>"+key.toString()+"</id>"+res+"</all>");
            results.collect(key, outputValue);
    }
```

it stuck at this level:

```
    12/11/26 06:19:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201210240845_0099
    12/11/26 06:19:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    12/11/26 06:19:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 20% reduce 0%
    12/11/26 06:19:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 0%
    12/11/26 06:19:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
    12/11/26 06:19:46 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 6%
    12/11/26 06:19:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
```

I run it locally and saw this:

```
    12/11/26 06:06:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
    12/11/26 06:06:48 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 5 sorted segments
    12/11/26 06:06:48 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 5 segments left of total size: 82159206 bytes
    12/11/26 06:06:48 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
    12/11/26 06:06:54 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
    12/11/26 06:06:55 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 66%
    12/11/26 06:06:57 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
    12/11/26 06:07:00 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
    12/11/26 06:07:03 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
    ...
    a lot of reduce > reduce ...
    ...
```

in the end , it finished the work. I want to ask:

1) what does it do in this reduce > reduce stage?

2) how can i improve this?

Answer (score 11):

When looking at the percentages, 0-33% is shuffle, 34%-65% is sort, 66%-100% is the actual reduce function.

Everything looks fine in your code, but I'll take a stab in the dark:

You are creating and re-recreating the string `res` over and over. Every time you get a new value, Java is creating a new string object, then creating another string object to hold the concatenation. As you can see, this can get out of hand when the string gets pretty big. Try using a [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead. Edit: [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is better than `StringBuffer`.

Whether or not this is the problem, you should change this to improve performance.

Comment: Use the StringBuilder instead of the buffer which is synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

Using StringBuilder solves it.  It improves the run time from 30 min to 30 sec.  I didn't think it would make such a difference.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: ... and respond via a comment!